# Create a function that contains an if statement inside of a for loop

Tags: r

I understand this isn't the most idiomatic way to approach the solution (i.e. not using a loop), but this is what I'm looking for. The function should loop through a data set's (`ds`) "a" column (`ds$a`). If column `a`'s number is equal to 1, the function should set the value of column `b` to 0. I really have no indication as to how to approach the problem, nor do I have any code to supply. Thanks in advance.

Edit: I know not using the loop is the best way to approach this, but again I'm looking for a way to make this work with the bounds of the title (Create a function that contains an if statement inside of a for loop) Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, there are a lot easier ways to do this than a loop.

But if you must...

```
# Create your dataframe
ds<-data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(1,1,1))
# Cycle through your dataframe
for (i in 1:nrow(ds)){
    if (ds$a[i]==1){ds$b[i]=0}
}
```

Comment: If looking for an easier way to approach this the ifelse function is always useful: ds$b <- ifelse(ds$a==1,0,ds$b). Thanks to @GuedesBF for pointing out a typo in my previous comment

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `replace` values in `b` conditionaly, you can use the `replace` function:

```
library(dplyr)

ds %>% mutate(b = replace(b, a==1, 0))
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to loop so that should do the trick for you :

```
my_df <- data.frame("a" = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 5, 1),
                "b" = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 5, 1),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

my_var <- which(my_df$a == 1)
if (length(my_var)) {
  my_df[my_var, "b"] <- 0
}
```